# Redirecting specific subdomain with NGINX to point to a different website while using SSL

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, http, 301-redirect

I have the following NGINX configuration:

```
# HTTP Redirect
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS Server
server {
    # Port to listen on, can also be set in IP:PORT format
    listen  443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate      bitnami/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  bitnami/certs/server.key;

    include  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/*.conf";

    location /status {
        stub_status on;
        access_log   off;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    error_page 404 403 500 503 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root /opt/bitnami/nginx/html;
        internal;
    }
}
```

This works spectacularly well for what it does, has my website and redirects any HTTP to HTTPS as needed. What I would like to do now is given a subdomain, such as `media.website.com`, I would like to redirect it to a different domain/location, but leave everything intact. (i.e. if I go to `website.com` it still takes me to my main site.) I also want this redirect to work for both HTTP and HTTPS.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add new `server` blocks so you can handle your specific subdomain, here your configuration file with the 2 new blocks

```
# HTTP Redirect
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS Server
server {
    listen  443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate      bitnami/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  bitnami/certs/server.key;

    server_name website.com www.website.com;

    include  "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/*.conf";

    location /status {
        stub_status on;
        access_log   off;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    error_page 404 403 500 503 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root /opt/bitnami/nginx/html;
        internal;
    }
}

# Redirect media.website.com (HTTP)
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name media.website.com;

    return 301 https://media.website.com$request_uri;
}

# Redirect media.website.com (HTTPS)
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name media.website.com;

    ssl_certificate      bitnami/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  bitnami/certs/server.key;

    return 301 https://newdomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

We also added the `server_name directive` to the existing HTTPS server block to explicitly specify the main domain and its www subdomain

Comment: Hi I just want to say this worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: You welcome :))